# Skip filter execution based on another filter asp .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, authorization

I have an action that is being authorized as following:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Agency, Subscribed, Normal")]
public ActionResult LocationProfile()
{}
```

what I need is to add another filter that gets executed before the authorization filter and if the result is true is doesn't execute the authorize attribute and proceeds to execute my action directly `(LocationProfile())`

is there any way to accomplish this task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to roll your [own version of the Authorize attribute](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/56fb14/custom-authorization-in-mvc/) that has that functionality built in.  Included from the C# corner post linked above:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute  
{  
   Entities context = new Entities(); // my entity  
   private readonly string[] allowedroles;  
   public CustomAuthorizeAttribute(params string[] roles)  
   {  
      this.allowedroles = roles;  
   }  
   protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)  
   {  
      bool authorize = false;  
      foreach (var role in allowedroles)  
      {  
         var user = context.AppUser.Where(m => m.UserID == GetUser.CurrentUser/* getting user form current context */ && m.Role == role &&  
         m.IsActive == true); // checking active users with allowed roles.  
         if (user.Count() > 0)  
         {  
            authorize = true; /* return true if Entity has current user(active) with specific role */  
         }  
      }  
      return authorize;  
   }  
   protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)  
   {  
      filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();  
   }  
}
```

In the AuthorizeCore method, you need to add your check to account for the situation describe.